# Vector equation of the line that passes through $P_0 = (-\frac{3}{2}, 4)$ and $P_1 = (1, -5)$

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

I was requested to find the vector equation of the line $L$ that passes through $P_0 = (-\frac{3}{2}, 4)$ and $P_1 = (1, -5)$. Since I am new to linear algebra, and I self-study (no professors to check my answer), I wanted to validate my solution. Here's what I did.

$I$. Let $\vec{a}=[-\frac{3}{2}, 4], \vec{b}=[1, 5]$ be the position vectors that point to the points $P_0$ and $P_1$ of $L$, respectively. Then

$$\begin{align} \vec{v} & =\vec{a} + \vec{b}  \\ & = [-\frac{1}{2}, 9]\end{align}$$

is a representation of the segment of $L$ that goes from $P_0$ to $P_1$.

$II$. It is clear that $\vec{v}$ is parallel to $L$. Then $L$ is given by the vectorial equation

$$\vec{r}= \vec{a} + t\vec{v} \space \space \tag{for any $t \in \mathbb{R}$}$$

where each possible $\vec{r}$ points to a point of $L$. An equivalent expression would have been

$$\vec{r}= \vec{b} + t\vec{v} \space \space \tag{for any $t \in \mathbb{R}$}$$

I made some of my thoughts explicit (for example, that we could use both $\vec{a}$ or $\vec{b}$ in the equation) to make sure that, if I am not understanding something correctly, it can be pointed out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should use $\vec v=\vec a-\vec b$. Minus sign, not plus

Comment: Generally, you would define $v$ as the vector $a-b$.

Comment: $P_0$ and $P_1$ are two elements of $\mathbb R ^2$: you can interpret them on a drawing as you want, here rather as "points" than as arrowed segments, right?

Comment: The equation $P_0 + t(P_1-P_0)$ is $P_0$ when $t=0$ and $P_1$ when $t=1$. You'll often seen it written $P_0 + t(P_1-P_0)=tP_1+(1-t)P_0$. The second form shows that it's a convex combination and can be generalized along those lines so it's worth familiarizing yourself with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You describe a line going through the origin, towards a point $\vec p$ as $\vec r=t\vec p$. For any parallel line, the slope is identical, so the coefficient of $t$ is the same, but we need to add a constant term:
$$\vec r(t)=\vec r_0+t\vec p$$
So, given your two points, we need to find $\vec r_0$ and $\vec p$. We can assume that $\vec r(0)=P_0$ and $\vec r(1)=P_1$. Then:
$$P_0=\vec r_0+0\vec p\\P_1=\vec r_0+1\vec p$$
From the first equation $\vec r_0=P_0$, so then in the second equation $\vec p=P_1-\vec r_0=P_1-P_0$.

Comment: This explains in detail what was said in the comment: I should have substracted, not added, the vectors $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$. Very clear answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We work in the real vector space $\mathbb R ^2$, we can add elements of $\mathbb R ^2$ as well as multiply them by any real number, the interpretation in a drawing is left free.

The affine line $l$ going through $P_0$ and $P_1$ is $l=P_0+\mathbb R (P_1-P_0)=(-\frac32,4)+\mathbb R ((1,-5)-(-\frac32,4))=(-\frac32,4)+\mathbb R (\frac52,-9)=\{(-\frac32+\frac52t,4-9t):t\in \mathbb R\}$

If we now consider the affine space associated with $\mathbb R ^2$, we have $\vec{P_0P_1}:=P_1-P_0$ and we can rewrite $l$ in the form $l=P_0+\mathbb R \vec{P_0P_1}$ which is probably the requested form, written nevertheless more explicitly above, where we say that we have parametrized the line $l$ with the parameter $t$.